# Back up a Git repo without losing large files

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

We are migrating our GitHub instance. That is, active repos are being migrated to a new GitHub instance. Older repos are being cloned to archival storage on a backup computer. The old GitHub instance will be decommissioned.

Some older repos have large files stored with LFS. I want to make sure I archive the files themselves, not just pointers. I have read documentation and looked online, but I don't understand everything.

Where are the large files stored? In Git LFS in the old GitHub instance?

When I clone a repo, I just get pointers unless I install lfs on the new backup computer.
I need to install it in the folder of each repo.

What brings the files and their history to the new repo?

---

Edit after reading an answer

If my questions are obvious, it is because I need to be careful. If my understanding is wrong, there will be no getting my data back after the old github is decommissioned.

from git lfs help

```
Git LFS is a system for managing and versioning large files in
association with a Git repository.  Instead of storing the large files
within the Git repository as blobs, Git LFS stores special "pointer
files" in the repository, while storing the actual file contents on a
Git LFS server.  The contents of the large file are downloaded
automatically when needed, for example when a Git branch containing
the large file is checked out.
```

Where is this server? Do I make a copy with git lfs install, or does that set up a client?

I get pointer files when I clone the repo. I get the latest real file when I check out a large file. At this point, do I have the history of the file?

---

from git lfs migrate help

```
Modes
-----

* info
    Show information about repository size.

* import
    Convert large Git objects to LFS pointers.
```

Export isn't mentioned here, but is described further down.

```
The 'export' mode migrates Git LFS pointer files present in the Git history out
of Git LFS, converting them into their corresponding object files.
```

git lfs migrate export doesn't sound like what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Say `git lfs help migrate`, which I discovered by saying `git lfs help` and reading the command descriptions for things that looked relevant.

Answer (score 0):

#### Backup older repos onto a backup computer

1. `git clone` to your backup computer
2. `git lfs install` to enable git lfs on that repo
3. Run `git lfs fetch --all` to fetch all LFS files and cache the locally on the backup computer.

#### Restore the above backup to another remote git repo with LFS support

1. Create an empty git repo on your new server, note the repo URL
2. Run `git remote show origin` to display the local backup's remote
3. Run `git remote set-url origin NEW_REMOTE_REPO_URL` to update the remote URL
4. Run `git remote show origin` to verify
5. Run `git push --all` to restore the local backup to remote
6. Run `git lfs push origin --all` to push all local cached LFS files to the new server.